# How Runnable Implemented class Looks like?

Tags: java

New in Java so bear with me :)

I'm using JFrame, where to handle events using EventQueue.invokeLater.

Here is the code snippet

```
public class Library extends JFrame {
    static Library frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame= new Library();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

My question is when Runnable is implemented by Anonymous class then how it looks like. I'm thinking it looks like below when new Object is created of Anonymous Class.

```
public class Anonymous implements Runnable {

    Anonymous(){
        Thread newThread = new Thread(this);
        newThread.run();  //from here my above it enters into above implementation of run method and executes the code within it. Is it correct ?
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){     
        Runnable Object = new Anonymous();      
    }
}
```

Is it the way it works when we implement Runnable in above manner ? If no can anyone help me to understand this ?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you run the code and see if it does what you expect? What is the whole first code snippet for? It doesn't seem related to what you are asking.

Comment: @csmckelvey, yes that could be...but may I know please how can I test this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you implement an interface you have to provide all the methods for that interface.  This is sometimes called Programming by Contract.

If Anonymous implements Runnable it has to have a run() method.  Then you create an instance of Anonymous and invoke that.

```
Anonymous annon = new Anonymous();
 EventQueue.invokeLater(annon);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: Yes that's true...I've not added because its implemented already in my first code snippet. I just want to know Am I on right understanding track...? That's how Thread gets created and works for that object when we use new Runnable() in my first code snippet ?

Comment: Your Runnable has no run method so it won't compile, and yes in the first snippet it looks good - just move that run method to the Runnable class

Comment: Can you please tell me when the run() method called when this happens "(new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();", Its a code from the link you have shared ?

Comment: Yes - calling start() will trigger run() to execute at some point (usually immediately).

Answer (score 0):

Runnable is just an interface and it's implemented like any other. The fact that it's broadly used doesn't make it particular in terms of implementation (don't associate it with threads or anything it usually shows up next to).

There are many ways to provide an implementation for an interface, of which the most common are:

**1 - Define a class and implement interface**

***Note that your declaration is invalid because it does not provide an implementation for the `run` method.***

```
class Anonymous implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            frame= new Library();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Which is something you can use with:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Anonymous());
```

**2 - Inner classes**, like in your first example. This is a full class that Java compiles as an implementation of your interface

**3 - Lambdas**: these will work becaue `Runnable` is a functional interface:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
    try {
        frame= new Library();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

**4 - Method references:** Assuming a static method `Library.makeFrameVisible`:

```
private static void makeFrameVisible() {
    try {
        frame= new Library();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can call it using a method reference:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(Library::makeFrameVisible);
```

All of the above are possible ways to make a `Runnable` interface, and you'll see runnable instances in many forms, including the ones above...